# Where is the best place to save temporary files in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I am busy writing an application that runs under windows

Where is the correct place to save temporary files ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you are using .NET, please use [Path.GetTempPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx).  This will guarantee that you use the temporary directory assigned to the user that runs your application, regardless of where it is stored.

If you browse the file system, you will notice that there are many "temp" directories:

- ~\Temp
- ~\Windows\Temp
- ~\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp

... and many more.  Some of these paths are OS-dependent, and won't be present on certain windows flavors.  So, save yourself some time and hassle, and let the .NET framework figure out where the "temp" path is located.

Comment: That - or use isolated storage, to which a user is always guaranteed to have write access!

Comment: Better yet, just use Path.GetTempFileName() which will generate the file name as well, and return the full path to it (in the appropriate temp folder).

Answer (score 12):

Use [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(VS.85).aspx) and and possibly [GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364991(VS.85).aspx) to determine where to put your temporary files.  This is the most reliable, enduser-friendly, and future proof way to get a temporary location for files.

Answer (score 6):

In the temp directory?

Use [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(VS.85).aspx) or in a batch file %TEMP%

Answer (score 5):

C:\Temp is NOT a good choice.

If you are using .Net use code like this:

```
           string baseFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

        string cfgFolder = Path.Combine(baseFolder, "MyAppName");


        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(cfgFolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(cfgFolder);
            }
        }
        catch { } // If no access, not much we can do.
```

to get a place for medium-term storage of app data, or Path.GetTempPath() for transient storage of data.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea to use `c:\Temp`? I'm not disagreeing with your point, I'm just curious as to your reasoning =)

Comment: C:\ might be a really small partition, and in many cases, normal (non-admin) users don't have write permissions on C:\ so they can't create C:\temp

Comment: Moreover, who's to say that C:\temp even exists on non-English Windows?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(VS.85).aspx) API, or the equivalent for your programming environment.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the language you are using:

```
string tempFolder = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
```

will return you the appropriate folder in C# for instance.

or, the environment variables TEMP or TMP if you must.

Answer (score -4):

C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\IsolatedStorage

Comment: Yes - but please use the documented Isolated Storage API and don't hardcode this path! On a system with a German version of Windows, this would be e.g. "C:\Dokumente\....." and if you hardcode this path, your app will break. FOLKS: IF THERE ARE APIs TO DO SOMETHING, **USE THEM**!!